# jQuery Mobile + phonegap: sudden change in scrolling direction causes scrolling to stop

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

On iOS, I have two pages.  Both are large  lists with images and links.

On one page, if I scroll quickly in one direction, then suddenly change to the other direction, the scrolling stops.  I have to start the scroll again to proceed.

On the other page, with similar content and mostly the same CSS, the scrolling works just as it would on any native iOS application with no problems.

I'm not sure what to provide to assist in diagnosis.  Are there variables to configure for some kind of sensitivity?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Seems like you've got at least one difference between the pages (and probably more than that). I'd start troubleshooting this issue by seeing what the difference(s) is/are.